# Smarty Object Property Inside Its PHP Tag

Tags: php, smarty

I have an smarty application where a series of addresses are being printed. It has a zip code too so at some point in template I am using.

```
{foreach item=i from=$members}
{$i.ZIP}
{/foreach}
```

The above code works though I am strictly making zip codes to 5 digits which I know can be accomplished by the following code.

```
{foreach item=i from=$members}
substr_replace("00000", {$i.ZIP}, 5 - strlen({$i.ZIP}));
{/foreach}
```

But the above code doesn't work and gives run time error. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use PHP code in a Smarty template unless you wrap it in {php} tags. In this case, you can avoid that by using [string_format](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.string.format.tpl).

I think this should do:

{$i.ZIP|string_format:"%05s"}